# How can I get the script name where an object of class is initiated within the class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I was looking for a way to get all the filenames where my class is imported and initiated an object of the class.

Is it possible to get? If yes, how?

Comment: No.  You do that with `grep` from a command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log portions of the call stack from the constructor for your class:

Here's an example that works for me:

In `test.mjs`:

```
export class Test {
    constructor() {
        let err = new Error();
        console.log(err.stack.split("\n")[1]);
    }
}
```

In `app.mjs`:

```
import { Test } from './test.mjs'

let x = new Test();
```

When I run `app.mjs`, it will cause this output:

```
at new Test (file:///x:/somepath/app.mjs:3:19)
```

Which is the file, line number and column that created an instance of my class (by calling the constructor).